# How can I increase the memory using exe4J?

Tags: install4j, exe4j

when converting a Java Application to an executable using exe4j, I want the exe to use as much memory as I assigned to the Application (1024MB). However, the executable only assigns 248MB and I'd like to know how to change that in exe4j?

thx in advance for your help

Comment: what you mean by memory assigned to the application( the vm parameters)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memory management is not influenced by exe4j. exe4j is just a native Java launcher generator, the JVM runs normally after than and -Xmx or -Xms VM parameters work as they do with other launchers.

Comment: Thanks Ingo. Then why does the executable feature a maximum of 248MB while the Java Application it came from uses the desired 1024MB? Any idea? thx in advance...

Comment: You can use -Xms instead of -Xmx to reserve all memory upfront

Comment: Thx again, Ingo. However, neither "-Xms512m" nor "-Xms512m -Xmx512" does change anything. The executable always works with 248MB. Is it to do with the fact that I write those commands into the .bat file of the Java Application?

Comment: -Xms512m is for the "VM parameters" text field in the "Java invocation" step. When calling the executable, pass -J-Xms512m